# Drupal Info file - Adding a file with files[] isnt working

Tags: php, class, drupal, module, include

I have a .php file that contains a class. I have been trying to add it so my modules info file with files[]. The info file looks like this:

```
name = Bitly API
description = Provides Bitly api functionality
core = 7.x
files[] = Oauth2social/socialmedia_oauth_connect.php
package = Source Control
```

The file exists in that location, but on module install im just getting:

Fatal error: Class 'socialmedia_oauth_connect' not found in /home/signdes/public_html/sites/all/modules/SourceControl/bitly/bitly.module on line 43

line 43 is in this function, specifically it is the instantiation of the class (first line):

```
<?php
    /** 
    * Function to make request to bit.ly
    * @param $url
    *       The pre-constructed URL to pass.
    */
    function bitly_request($url) {
        $oauth = new socialmedia_oauth_connect();
        $oauth->provider="Bitly";
        $oauth->client_id = variable_get('bitly_clientid', '');
        $oauth->client_secret = variable_get('bitly_clientsecret', '');
        $oauth->redirect_uri  ="http://ngiriraj.com/socialMedia/oauthlogin/bitly.php";

        $oauth->Initialize();

        $code = ($_REQUEST["code"]) ?  ($_REQUEST["code"]) : "";

        if(empty($code)) {
            $oauth->Authorize();
        }else{
            $oauth->code = $code;
    #       $oauth->getAccessToken();
            $getData = json_decode($oauth->getUserProfile());
            $oauth->debugJson($getData);
            print "Name :".$getData->data->full_name;
        }
    }
```

?>

is there any reason for files[] to not include the file? its always seemed a little hit and miss for me.

The file isn't appearing in the registry_file table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the module file. I had a debug line of code calling one of the hook functions from outside of a function. So when installing, the module file was called and an attempt to access the class immidiatly fired, bypassing drupal completly.

Really need to be more careful about changing test scripts into modules....